# Some browsers stopped uploading pages

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10

Chrome and Edge in windows 10 stopped oppening webpages. Firefox is ok when oppening the same pages, I have a portable version of Firefox 74.0(64-bit). Router Wifi is ok.

Firefox Network Settings
[image]

Edge gives me the message [Can’t connect to the proxy server.]

I tried to clean cash from chrome or reinstall it but useless.

I tried to install windows 10 again yet the problem remained.  It seems there is a network problem even during installation.

I tried installing windows 8 still the network problem during installation and after oppening Microsoft Explorer I got the message [resource (web proxy) is online but is not responding to connection.]

What cause this problem and how could it be fixed?

Edit:
I called my ISP and it directed me to change the configuration of the Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)
I changed the IP address and the DNS server addresses to a new set of numbers, and then it works and everything be ok.

I reinstalled windows 10 yet the problem has occurred again, the configuration reset to "obtain automatically" for the IP and the DNS. 
[image]

Comment: Try maybe to reboot the router. Do you use a proxy?

Comment: When your say that Firefox is OK, do you mean that when you try to open the same webpage, Firefox displays the page and Edge won't? If you go into Firefox preferences, General, then at the bottom of the page, in the Network settings, and click on Parameters, there must be four possibilities: no proxy, proxy auto-detect, use system proxy settings and manually configure proxy. Which is enabled (should be no proxy, but who know)? While you're there, look at the bottom of the popup if the "enable DNS via HTTPS" is enabled (should be by default). Screenshots would be appreciated, if in English...

Comment: @harrymc,  Rebooting does not work. I do not use a proxy.

Comment: @Didier, I made some edits, maybe that help.

Comment: Yeah, I see that, and you should enable "No proxy", and at the bottom, "DNS over HTTPS" too. That's in Firefox, which, if I understand correctly, worked anyway, so your issue is with Chrome or Edge, right?

Comment: Yes, the issue is with Chrome and Edge.

Comment: Which version of Edge do you use? The one that's built on top of Chromium, or the old one?

Comment: I was using the default settings now I have changed Firefox settings to "no proxy" and checked "DNS over HTTPS" .. Firefox stil works. Edge version is Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0 ------ Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.18363

Comment: In Edge, if you click on the three horizontal dots in the top right corner of the window, then on Settings (or Parameters, mine is in French), then Advanced, you can check proxy settings. In fact, it'll send you to Settings (for Windows) > Network and Internet > Proxy. What does it say there?

Comment: I have uploaded a screenshot for the Proxy

Comment: Do you still have internet if you disable "Automatically detect settings"?

Comment: @harrymc, I disabled "Automatically detect settings" and it seem to worked! .. Firefox is working and Edge is working ... no problem now for me.... it works. ... but I wonder because I changed the default settings of windows I have just installed and never done that before.

Comment: It's a default setting.

Comment: @Didier, It wasn't in my case. I had to disable it to make windows run ok as harrym has advised.

Comment: Yes, I understand. What I mean is, when you first install Windows, this option is enabled by default. You can check it in Settings, as you did, or in Control Panel > Internet and Sharing > Internet options (Connections tab). Nowadays, most ISPs hand you a modem that's preconfigured to work on any operating system out of the box, but some users like to bridge that connection by adding a router downstream, to cater to a larger number of devices, or simply because they're used to do that (or other technical reasons). Proxy settings belong in the enterprise world, not the average user, I think.

Comment: @Didier, Sounds new information for me thank you for help. but , I just like to know why I have to  disable "Automatically detect settings". why not a normal connection from the ISP. I think I have to ask them about that.

Comment: Yes, it's best to get the official version. Bottomline is, you can now surf the Web with both browsers, and that, in my book, goes in the Wins column. Cheers mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have disabled
*Settings > Network & Internet > Proxy > Search > Automatically detect settings*,
and now everything works.

This setting is supposed to be harmless, but in your case causes a connection
problem in browsers that pay attention to this system setting.
Firefox still works, since it has its own proxy settings and does not use
the system ones.

I do not know why a dummy proxy is detected by Windows on your internet connection.
It might be worthwhile to get in touch with the Support of your ISP and ask
for an explanation.
In the meantime you may continue with this option as disabled, until you get
a good explanation from your ISP.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help yet what does it mean by "a proxy is detected by Windows"? and why my ISP is involved with that?

Comment: Because your ISP may have blocked the use of a proxy, for security or legal (I don't know where you live) reasons. As harrymc said, Firefox uses its own network settings and only relies on Windows for connectivity, both hardware and software. Edge is made by Microsoft and part of Windows now, hence the different network settings. Check with your ISP if regulations in your country prohibit the use of a proxy, but frankly, you don't need one, not for your everyday Web surfing. EDIT: some malware sometimes install a fake proxy to loopback update attempts by your antivirus. Worth a check...

Comment: @Didier Yes I have to check with them again,  the previous time they gave me numbers to configure the IP and the DNS addresses anyway  thank you so much for your help. and have a great day!

Comment: You too! Bye and enjoy!